# Gaussian rationals with rational norm

Tags: normed-spaces, rational-numbers

Looking for information on Gaussian rationals with rational norm.

A gaussian rational is a complex number of the form z = p + qi where p and q are rationals.

Taking only those that have |z| = $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$ is rational. These form a group under multiplication.

Trying to find any papers or texts studying this structure. Thanks.

Comment: [These lecture notes](http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~amyekut/lectures/pythagoras/notes_compact.pdf) look helpful, [and there is a related Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_rational_points_on_the_unit_circle)

Comment: Letting $r=|z|$, your question is precisely about triples $(p,q,r)$ of rationals with $p^2+q^2=r^2$. By multiplying by common denominator, we get Pythagorean triples, which have very well-studied structure.